can't signin to ubuntu due to sign-in loop
I am experiencing couple of errors on my ubuntu machine from the booting process to the sign in screen.

My Ubuntu is in emergency mode. Whenever I bootup my machine it shows the below message

You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "Journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, or "exit" to continue bootup. Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):


When I do nothing on the previous screen it automatically disappears and the login screen appears. When I try to login it again shows me the login screen. I am stuck in a kind of loop in which I enter my credentials and the login screen again show up.
i have attached the video which demonstrates this error.

What I Tried:
I followed this answer to exit from the emergency mode. See the logs below while following this method.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i
root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 3.02 GiB, 3241230336 bytes, 6330528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 452 KiB, 462848 bytes, 904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 53.26 MiB, 55844864 bytes, 109072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 485.52 MiB, 509100032 bytes, 994336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 237.21 MiB, 248729600 bytes, 485800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 73.88 MiB, 77463552 bytes, 151296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 63.45 MiB, 66531328 bytes, 129944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG HM321HI 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A2FF50BE-48F0-4841-9151-93AF1D9F76B7

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   2203647   2201600    1G EFI System
/dev/sda2    2203648  35758079  33554432   16G Linux swap
/dev/sda3   35758080 245473279 209715200  100G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  245473280 625139711 379666432  181G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 28.82 GiB, 30943995904 bytes, 60437492 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876F-C8245AF921E0

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       64  9828451  9828388  4.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2  9828452  9838519    10068  4.9M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  9838520  9839119      600  300K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  9842688 60437428 50594741 24.1G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 12.32 MiB, 12922880 bytes, 25240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 349.7 MiB, 366682112 bytes, 716176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
root@ubuntu:~# umount /dev/sda3
umount: /dev/sda3: not mounted.
root@ubuntu:~# fsck -y /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sda3: clean, 457629/6553600 files, 6125915/26214400 blocks
root@ubuntu:~# 

The recent setting I remember that was changed by me was  changing the display manager from Wayland to Xorg. but there's no file .Xauthority file present in the root.
here are journalctl -xb logs.sorry the logs are too lengthy and askubuntu limits the length
Please get me rid of this thing.
Thank You.
UPDATE:
After going through the logs, I see that there is an issue with the mount of my HDD (sda) partitions. so I did lsblk and saw that my /home partition which is sda4 is not mounted and after mounting the partition, restarted the Display Manager and I successfully logged in to my Ubuntu through Display Manager. Here is what i did.
a-sajjad72@HaLF-MenTaL:~$ lsblk | grep sda
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0   100G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0   181G  0 part
a-sajjad72@HaLF-MenTaL:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda4
a-sajjad72@HaLF-MenTaL:~$ lsblk | grep sda
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0   100G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0   181G  0 part /home
a-sajjad72@HaLF-MenTaL:~$ sudo systemctl restart gdm3

But the emergency mode is still there. and also I have to do this at every boot to made my login. What will be solution.
EDIT:
as per @steeldriver comment i tried the journalctl with extra arguments here is the results. but unfortunaltely I can't able to run fsck manually on /dev/sda3 manually. because it shows the target is busy. it's my root partition. And I got this message during unmounting the /dev/sda3
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00001003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00001003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00001003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00001003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00002003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00002003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00004003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: Internal clock never stabilised.
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x0000c001
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01f70000 | Host ctl: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00004003
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x00ff0083 | Sig enab: 0x00ff0083
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x21e608b2 | Caps_1:   0x00002077
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000000 | Max curr: 0x00000064
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000000 | Resp[1]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000000 | Resp[3]:  0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
Jun 28 11:44:39 HaLF-MenTaL kernel: mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Jun 28 11:44:53 HaLF-MenTaL systemd-fsck[982]: fsck failed with exit status 36.
Jun 28 11:44:53 HaLF-MenTaL systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0b05db49\x2dfda2\x2d4e64\x2d96df\x2d0bfda97f0be4.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/0b05db49-fda2-4e64-96df-0bfda97f0be4.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0b05db49\x2dfda2\x2d4e64\x2d96df\x2d0bfda97f0be4.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0b05db49\x2dfda2\x2d4e64\x2d96df\x2d0bfda97f0be4.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 40 and the job result is failed.


It might be helpful to run journalctl -xb with the additional parameter -p 3 or --priority=3 to focus on actual error conditions

... I can see that /dev/sda4 had errors and systemd-fsck apparently failed to correct them. You seem to have run fsck manually on /dev/sda3 though?
